# check argument value of d3 function

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, firebug, force-layout

I would like to check the value of the "d" argument in a function from this code snippet:

```
var force = force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(json.nodes)
    .links(json.links)
    .linkDistance(function (d){return d;}) //I need to know the "d" value to decide what return
    .size([width, height])
    .start();
```

I am using firebug, but I can't to enter in that function. I tried to put an alert inside the function but it didn't work.

Comment: *"I am using firebug, but I can't to enter in that function."* You should be able to. *"I tried to put an alert inside the function but it didn't work."* That suggests a problem outside the code you've quoted, or that `linkDistance` doesn't support a callback (and so never calls the function you're passing it).

Comment: Just to be clear: `.linkDistance(function(3) { return d;})` passes a function into `linkDistance`. That function isn't **called** unless `linkDistance` calls it via the argument it receives. Is that really what you mean to do?

Comment: You can use a [`debugger` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) in the `linkDistance` function to pause execution there, if it is executed at all. This might help you more than an `alert`.

Answer (score 1):

The d3 documentation provides you what is the argument :

> 

## force.linkDistance([distance])

If distance is specified, sets the target distance between linked nodes to the specified value. If distance is not specified, returns the layout's current link distance, which defaults to 20. If distance is a constant, then all links are the same distance. Otherwise, if distance is a function, then the function is evaluated for each link (in order), being passed the link and its index, with the this context as the force layout; the function's return value is then used to set each link's distance. The function is evaluated whenever the layout starts. Typically, the distance is specified in pixels; however, the units are arbitrary relative to the layout's size.

>

so, if the argument is a function, the first argument is the link and the second argument is the index of the link. You shouldn't forget to associate data to the force layout before apply the function.

I have got an example here:

```
force
    .nodes(json.nodes)
    .links(json.links);

    force.linkStrength(function(d,i) {return (json.links[i].isMyLeaf ? .01: 1);});
```

in my json file I define isMyLeaf for each link.